# Pyinstaller gives Fatal error failed to execute script bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

[Fatal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJpqf.png)

The program works fine as a Python script (.py file) but doesn't work when I convert it to a Windows Executable file (.exe file) using Pyinstaller.
Pyinstaller keeps giving me the error: `Fatal error detected. Failed to execute script bot.` I looked at some other posts but they didn't help me.

Note: I did `pyinstaller -w -F --onefile bot.py`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the time to use the proper punctuation and formatting in your question. This sort of post looks very unprofessional.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the actual code; this type of error may be a **problem with your script** (i.e. there's an error in your code, like if there's dependencies not correctly included), not a problem with `pyinstaller`, since the code you're running really should work. By the way, `-F` and `--onefile` are the same thing. I recommend not using `-w` for now, to debug, until you find and correct the error.